# Drupal 7: how to return a 404 page not found instead of a view

Tags: php, drupal-7, http-status-code-404, drupal-views

With the views module (drupal 7) I created a page.

Page settings
Path: /news

If I go to ../news I get the news page, what I expect.

When adding a trailing slash at the end I can add everything (after the trailing slash) and the news page will still show up. For instance: ../news/123 etc.

How can I return a 404 instead of the news page? I don't mind using PHP to get it done.

(When I go to ../news123 I do get a 404 what I want).

thx!

Comment: See also this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/views-path-prevents-404-page-from-showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source](https://skvare.com/blog/non-existent-urls-views-2):

The solution is to edit the view by adding an Argument of Node: Nid. Set it to Display all values, Validator: Node, and Argument type of Node ID.

Set Action to take if argument does not validate: Hide view / Page not found (404). Update the Argument and save the view.

Comment: Perfect! A very simple, but helpful solution. Thx!